# She may/might not be Anil's sister

Tags: modal-verbs

> She **may** not be Anil's sister.
>
> She **might** not be Anil's sister.

What's the difference?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Just confirming...

Comment: that's what I'm asking... confirming **what?**

Comment: @MaulikV I think it's a straight question that deserves a straight answer. It's not one of those which requires research imo.

Comment: What is 'verb' is also a straight question. I was just concerned about the 'efforts' put or at least the opinion of the OP about the question itself. @Araucaria

Comment: @MaulikV I don't think that's necessary in this case to make it a good question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP accepted the first answer, and it is clearly wrong.  That isn't the question's fault, but unless OP un-accepts the answer, we run the risk of having an incorrect answer memorialized permanently.

Comment: @Adam No, closing the question absolutely guaranteed memorialising the wrong answer. Surely that's obvious? As demonstrated by the fact that neither lucky - see comment above - nor anyone else can now give a good answer.

Comment: @Auracaria Point taken.

Comment: @Lucky & Everybody: Sorry for the confusion. My problem is, I see **may** and **might** interchangeable everywhere. For eg. **I might see you tomorrow.** or **I may see you tomorrow.** I got scared of incoming -ve votes after reading comment...

Answer (score 3):

***Explanation for the examples given in the question:***

*May* and *might* are used interchangeably, when expressing a possibility or uncertainty (a situation when we are not sure of something). This is the case in your example. We might imagine a conversation that goes like this:

> A: Anil's sister came to pick up his things. Where did you put them?
>
> B: Have you checked her ID? She **may/might** not be Anil's sister.

So, speaker B is not sure whether the visitor is Anil's sister.

In a different situation the same interchangeable usage would apply:

> A: Who is that girl in a blue dress?
>
> B: She **may/might** be Anil's sister.

Again, B is guessing, but isn't sure.

- [Some sources](https://books.google.rs/books?id=1XixeA7xHrcC&pg=PA217&dq=%22may+and+might%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22may%20and%20might%22&f=false) suggest that usage of may/might implies equal probability (in this example it is equally possible that the girl is or is not Anil's sister).
- [Other sources](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/what-is-the-difference-between-may-and-might) state that if something is **less likely** you should use **might** and if it's **more likely** you should use **may** (but this is a **flexible rule**).
- In formal or academic language, **may** should be used to express **possibility**:

> A Giant sequoia tree may reach the height of 85 meters.

---

***Other cases where may and/or might are used:***

- *Polite requests*: both are used, but might is considered rare, or is used for very formal requests (this might be a BrE/AmE difference - see references 1, 2 and 3).
  But:

> May I help you?

is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=may+I+help+you%2C+might+I+help+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmay%20I%20help%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmight%20I%20help%20you%3B%2Cc0) than 'Might I help you' and can be considered idiomatic.

- For *polite suggestions* both are used:

> Next time you might try...
> You may want to consider...

- For [*emphatic refusal*](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/may-might-may-have-and-might-have#sthash.qBQQyPS9.dpuf) **may** is used:

> You **may not** borrow the car until you can be more careful with it.

Note that this is not likely to be the case with your examples; nobody can forbid someone to be someone else's sibling (such situation would be rather absurd).

- For *giving permission*, may (and not might) is used:

> You may enter.

Again, this is not the case when you say: 'She may be Anil's sister' - in that sentence nobody is giving her the permission to be Anil's sister; they are speculating who the girl is.

- As the *past tense of may in requests*, might is used:

> She asked whether she might get a few days off.

- For the things that *have possibly happened* **may have/might have** is used, but for counterfactuals (things that could have, but actually didn't happen) might have is preferred (although may have is not unheard of):

> I think that comment may/might have offended some people.
>
> If they had lived in another time, their lives might have been different.

- There are many idiomatic expressions that use may and/or might, such as:

[may as well/might as well](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/may-as-well-and-might-as-well), where [both are common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=may+as+well%2C+might+as+well&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmay%20as%20well%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmight%20as%20well%3B%2Cc0); or [be that as it may](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-that-as-it-may) which you should probably use instead of 'be that as it might' since the former is [considerably more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+that+as+it+may%2C+be+that+as+it+might&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20that%20as%20it%20may%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20that%20as%20it%20might%3B%2Cc0)

---

References:

1. [Learn English- British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/may-might-may-have-and-might-have) - have a look at the exercise at this link, it's a good one.
2. [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/what-is-the-difference-between-may-and-might)
3. [The Ultimate Phrasal Verb Book](https://books.google.rs/books?id=1XixeA7xHrcC&pg=PA217&dq=%22may+and+might%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22may%20and%20might%22&f=false) by Carl W. Hart
4. [Oxford Dictionaries Language matters](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/may-or-might)
5. [Advanced Grammar in Use](https://books.google.rs/books?id=YZAoAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22may+and+might%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22may%20and%20might%22&f=false) by Martin Hewings
6. [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/could-may-and-might?q=may+and+might)

Comment: Aside (slightly off topic): According to [etymoonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=might&allowed_in_frame=0) historically *might* is the past tense of *may*, but as you can see, nowadays there are many other usages of *might*. Related to this question on ELU: [May & might: what's the right context](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7/may-might-whats-the-right-context) and [May, might confusion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8470/may-might-confusion)